# Style the select tag in antDesign

Tags: reactjs

I have to use this component in my application:

```js
const options = [
  { value: "gold" },
  { value: "lime" },
  { value: "green" },
  { value: "cyan" }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    placeholder={["good"]}
    style={{ width: "20%" }}
    options={options}
  />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

The idea is, that i want to change it in the next way: When i will select a value from dropdown i don't want do display it in input, but i want to keep by default the text `good` in the input, and when i will choose an option, that option should not change the `good` placeholder. How to do this?

**demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-tag-render-ant-design-demo-j9edb?file=/index.js:149-428

EX: when will select a option from select, that option should not be displayed, and the placeholder should be in the input

Comment: @keikai, do you have any idea?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean ?

Comment: @Bahtiyar, i want, when i will select a value from dropdown, to keep the placeholder visible on input (i don't want to see in the input selected value). Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: okey I understand. May be you can do with javascript. When will select , clear text of Select component using javascript.